# Join tables with specific order

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables, for example: Teacher and Pupil and table LastViewedPupil with fields who watched him and when (teacherId & pupilId). So I want to return the list of Pupils that was ordered by last viewed date, but there are not all pupils inside LastViewedPupil, but last few for example, I want to show after that ordered by date all left records no matter in wich order, how can I do that?

I can do without last part like

```
select * from Pupil as p, (
    select * from LastViewedPupil lvp where lvp.teacherId = 5 ORDER BY lastViewDate
) as lvp where lvp.pupilId = p.pupilId;
```

Or should I add corresponding records in LastViewDatePupil for all pupils or need to Join table itself (sounds awkward)?

Comment: not particularly sure I understand what you're asking, but I think `SELECT p.*, lvp.* FROM Pupil as p, LastViewedPupil as lvp WHERE lvp.teacherId = 5 AND lvp.pupilId = p.pupilId ORDER BY lvp.lastViewDate` Should cover you

Comment: Oh, that's the same thing, but I need to add to this records all, that left in Pupil table, except ordered - they should stay first in list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this one:

```
SELECT p.*
LEFT JOIN LastViewedPupil lvp ON p.id = lvp
WHERE lvp.teacher_id = 5
ORDER BY lvp.lastViewDate DESC
```

I'm not sure if that query puts `NULL` at the beginning or at the end. If that doesn't order the results properly, try this other. I used a `CASE` for reordering data

```
SELECT p.*, 
   CASE WHEN lvp.lvp.lastViewDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0, END AS notNullfirst FROM Pupil p
LEFT JOIN LastViewedPupil lvp ON p.id = lvp
WHERE lvp.teacher_id = 5
ORDER BY notNullfirst, lvp.lastViewDate DESC
```

Comment: The second one helped!